# How do I move my AnkiDroid data to external SD card?

Tags: external-sd, ankidroid

My phone is Samsung Galaxy J7. Internal Memory is full and I want to move this large pp to SD. How can I do so?

Answer (score 6):

It is NOT recommended by the AnkiDroid team. Here is the Github issue about this: https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/issues/3106

Someone reported success using the procedure below, please make backups and remember that you are on your own if you choose to do it.

1. Go to your external SD card folder via file management app and create a folder with
   the apk's package name ("com.ichi2.anki") containing an AnkiDroid sub-folder: the exact path depends on
   your devices. 
   E.g. On my Desire 820, the path of the external SD card folder is "/storage/ext_sd/",
   and after I created the folders the complete path of the AnkiDroid folder is "/storage/ext_sd/Android/data/com.ichi2.anki/AnkiDroid/"
2. Install AnkiDroid, open it, and change the storage path to the path I mentioned
   above.

Specifying where your AnkiDroid collection is:

[image: AnkiDroid directory setting]

Comment: This did not work for me. What is the path for the Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 6.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use anki in external storage above Marshmallow, use the following folder:

```
/storage/Your_SD_Card/Android/data/com.ichi2.anki/Ankidroid
```

Replace `Your_SD_Card` with your SD card's name. Check it with your file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are facing problem by this method is only because you are not correctly putting your external storage name properly best way is to download Es file explorer and copy the file location and paste it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYoQ_7tT0I0

Comment: Just use any other file manager. ES File Explorer has been removed from Google Play following findings of click fraud.